# Netbeans: how to change @author

Tags: netbeans, javadoc, netbeans-7

When creating a new class or interface in Netbeans IDE, an "@author ...." tag appears. How to change its value? If possible, I would like to change it by using Netbeans menu and not by editing some config files :) I'm using Netbeans 7.2

Answer (score 242, accepted):

**Steps:**

1. Go to **Tools** -> **Templates**.
2. Click on **Settings** button. A new panel with template settings will appear in your IDE:
3. Uncomment the last line and change the value of "user" to what ever you like to be inserted after the **@author** tag.

**PS**: I think this blog will better explain [how to update author template](http://progers-blog.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-change-author-property-in.html)

Comment: You might also want to do a Find and Replace(Ctrl + Shift + H) for changing all the already place **@ author** tag in the project. As the change above doesn't change the already placed **@ author**.

Comment: And don't use the angle-brackets in the dummy version initially provided, for enclosing your e-mail address. The javadoc processor will think it's HTML, and call it an error.

Comment: But this is a global setting? Can author be specific for a project?

Comment: @Storm, no, I haven't.

Comment: @Storm @ zygimantus .... Have you guys tried updating License Header and use it  as template for project .??

Comment: @RavindraShekhawat I hadn't found any options for overriding templates in project's settings. There is License Header overriding option, but if we add `@author <name>` at the end of license, this string will be in the beginning of the file, before namespaces, for example. While we expect that `@author` annotation should be right before class definition. Maybe I misunderstood your suggestion?

Answer (score 16):

In case someone else finds this while looking for the same functionality in Eclipse: Window -> Show View -> Templates

Answer (score 2):

-In netbeans go to Tools -> Templates -> Settings 
-last line of the file, write like this user=xyz

N:B: Instead of xyz you could be used your name.

Answer (score -1):

I could not find any template or Code completion in Netbeans 15 to get rid of that @author when I added a javadoc to a class. Hence I added another code completion, cc, and let it add the javadoc.

[Additional Code Completion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZO5PY.png)