# How do I set custom @author name in netbean?

Tags: javascript, php, netbeans-8

I have changed user to my information in user.properties in netbean,

```
(Eg.user = JOHN<john@gmail.com>),
```

but it can only work in php file ,not working in js(javascript) file @author name? How to do to get @author in JS...!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Netbeans: how to change @author](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15922390/netbeans-how-to-change-author)

Comment: yes @Tomasz, i did the same as described ,php is ok ,js file is not work !!! Is it normal!!!