# How to change the user property (@author template generation) for a single project

Tags: netbeans, customization

I know [how to change the identity of the author for the whole platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15922390/netbeans-how-to-change-author), but how can I do that for a single project? I use Netbeans for various kinds of projects, and I use different identities (pseudos, contact e-mails) for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's plugin for that:
[template-settings4p](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/57583/template-settings4p)