# How does netbeans determine the @author comment?

Tags: netbeans

My name is spelt wrong in the @author comment, I also found this problem with Monodevelop. Where is the name taken from? So I can change it at it's source. I am on windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netbeans: how to change @author](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15922390/netbeans-how-to-change-author)

Comment: @Luke Glazebrook No, this is a problem with windows, my name is spelt wrong, but in my settings it's spelt right. I want to find the original source of this problem, not just change it in netbeans